# iSCSI and runaway log file

Tags: centos, logs

I have a OpenVZ VPS running CentOS 5.7 that I've been using to get some sysadmin experience.

I found a log file called brcm-iscsi.log in /var/log and it's getting big (140 MB).

```
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Initialize logger using log file: /var/log/brcm-iscsi.log
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Started BRCM iSCSI stack: Ver 0.6.2.13
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Build date: Fri Jul 22 01:19:02 EDT 2011
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Running on sysname: 'Linux', release: '2.6.18-274.7.1.el5.028stab095.1', version '#1 SMP Mon Oct 24 20:49:24 MSD 2011' machine: 'i686'
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Initialize logger using log file: /var/log/brcm-iscsi.log
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Started BRCM iSCSI stack: Ver 0.6.2.13
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Build date: Fri Jul 22 01:19:02 EDT 2011
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]Running on sysname: 'Linux', release: '2.6.18-274.7.1.el5.028stab095.1', version '#1 SMP Mon Oct 24 20:49:24 MSD 2011' machine: 'i686'
WARN  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]nic_utils Error when scanning path: /sys/class/iscsi_host/[No such file or directory]
INFO  [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]signal handling thread ready
ERR   [Sun Dec 18 20:15:42 2011]NIC_NL waiting binding to NETLINK_ISCSI socket
ERR   [Sun Dec 18 20:15:43 2011]NIC_NL waiting binding to NETLINK_ISCSI socket
ERR   [Sun Dec 18 20:15:44 2011]NIC_NL waiting binding to NETLINK_ISCSI socket
```

And every second since then I've had that line. I don't quite understand what is going on, so I'm hoping someone could tell me how to fix the underlying problem rather than just deleting the log file. I did Google this and found http://drup.org/brcm-iscsilog-filling-hard-drive which seems to just disable iSCSI and ignore any more errors. Is there a better/safer/preferable way of stopping this error logging?

I don't know much about iSCSI - I get that it's a SAN protocol, but that's about it. I've certainly never setup any volumes outside of the disk space I got with my VPS. Could my VPS be relying on this in some way? I wouldn't want to trash it, although I'm getting quite practiced at reloading the VPS... I also wouldn't want to screw up anyone else's nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google it and you come up with plenty links (Check out this one, for instance https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/open-iscsi/S3ps_mqzd_k) If you do not know what iscsi is (basically, SCSI over the wire: low level access to network disks) chances are good you won't be using it any time soon so you can remove/stop all the related cruft.